# Using a different layout file for devise login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to use a different layout file for logging into devise.

I've tried a static page but I get the error `undefined local variable or method 'resource'`.

Currently, in my application controller I have:

```
layout :layout_by_resource

protected

def layout_by_resource
  if devise_controller?
    "signin"
  else
    "application"
  end
end
```

The problem with this is that every devise view uses the layout file 'login', which isn't good because I currently use devise's edit registration form for a account page.

Anybody know the best way to use a different layout file for signing into devise?

Answer (score 2):

You might need to do two things to make this work.

1) Create seperate controllers inheriting from the Devise controllers, with your stated layout call. [Instructions](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#getting-started/configuring-controllers)

2) To customize the views themselves further even copy over the views. [Instructions](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#getting-started/configuring-views) Might not be nescessary.

Regarding 1) Controller(s): If you just want to customize login, you'd need to target the sessions controller.

```
# app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  layout :layout_for_action

protected

  def layout_for_action
    if params[:action] == '...' # See what the action is called internally beforehand
      "signin"
    else
      "application"
    end
  end

end
```

You then need to instruct Devise to use your controller in `config/routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :admins, :controllers => { :sessions => "sessions" }
```

Comment: Ok, I created the sessions controller but I'm confused on what to add to my routes files. From the instructions, I added `devise_for :admins, :controllers => { :sessions => "admins/sessions" }` but I don't know what to replace :admins with and the admins/sessions.

Comment: Added it. `"admins/sessions"` is a namespaced controller, but you just have a normal `"sessions"` one.

Comment: Any errors, any log messages to debug? You might need to restart your development server after such changes.

Comment: To find out where exactly I can highly recommend the [**BetterErrors**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/402-better-errors-railspanel) gem. It will give you more insight into your app. Right now I'd assume that you named your controller `class Admin::SessionsController...` instead of just `class SessionsController...`.

Comment: I've got BetterErrors but that error is what Pow came back with. Nope, it's called SessionsController

Answer (score -1):

You can run this command

```
rails generate devise:views
```

This will generate devise views files for you to customize your layout.